# Worksheet names to list(of string)

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm getting a list of worksheet names in a workbook using VB.net via the Excel Interop. I was looping through all the sheets to get a list of the worksheet names.

But I'm looking for a faster way. I was poking around and found `.Cast`. That prompted this question. I couldn't find anything on the internet about this possibility.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Function GetWorksheetNames(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook) As List(Of String)
    Dim lis As List(Of String)
    lis = wb.Worksheets.Cast(Of Excel.Worksheet)().Select(Function(x) x.Name)
Return lis
End Function
```

Failed with this error: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

So how do I get the list of worksheet names using `.Cast`?

[MSDN: Enumerable.Cast(Of TResult) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine, but the declaration of the variable storing the results (`lis`) is wrong. Note that `LINQ` methods return `Enumerable`-like types, which need to be expressly converted into a specific collection type (`List(Of String)` in this case). Your code can be fixed in the following way:

```
lis = wb.Worksheets.Cast(Of Excel.Worksheet)().Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToList
```

Alternatively, you might not perform the conversion to a list at any point and just rely on the type being output by the `LINQ` query. For example:

```
Dim lis2 = xlWbSource.Worksheets.Cast(Of Excel.Worksheet)().Select(Function(x) x.Name)

For Each name As String In lis2

    'Use name as you want

Next
```

Comment: Amazing! I was so close. Thanks!

Comment: @D_Bester yes, really close :)